# How to fix the white screen in browser during react build?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am pretty new to React and I am trying to understand why I have a blank browser

my App.js is:

```js
import React from 'react';
import TodoList from './TodoList'

function App() {
  return (
    <TodoList />
  )
}
```

my Index.js is:

```js
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

My Todolist (Project name)

```js
import React from 'react'

export default function TodoList() {
  return (
    <div> 
        Hello World!
    </div>
  )
}
```

On my other project, I have  Index.css as `

```js
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Index.html as

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
        <script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.development.js"></script>
        <script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6/babel.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="root"></div>
        <script src="index.js" type="text/babel"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

and index.js as `ReactDOM.render(<h1>Hello, everyone!</h1>, document.getElementById("root"))`

all of these show a blank screen when ran.[blank screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GMjWR.png)

I have tried to do some research, added "homepage": ".", to Package.json file and even tried to downgrade react script from 5.0 to 4.0 nothing worked.

Answer (score 0):

export default App;
Add this at the end of app.js file

ohter than that i am not seeing any problem

Comment: I added export default App; but I still have a blank screen

Comment: import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import App from './App';

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>
);
I am also beginner so if i struck somewhere and can't get out, I code that thing again from scratch or refer to youtube, and i also noticed that  my index.js file looks like this 

Comment: how do you code from scratch as a beginner?